# Strange Eloquent belongsTo() return null. Foreign key property being displayed but not accessible

Tags: laravel, eloquent, null

Environment : PHP 8.1.4, Laravel 9

Eloquent Model : Market Model, Sequence Model

Sequence Model belongs to Market Model.

```
// Sequence.php
public function market()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Market::class);
}
```

Market and Sequence table has each data properly..

Problem is, Sequence model cannot access its `market` properly. It looks like `$this->market()` works fine but `$this->market` returns null.

```
// Some method in Sequence.php

private function loadCollection(): CandleCollection
{
    dd($this->market(), $this->market);
    return $this->collection = $this->market->createCandleCollection($this->label, $this->size);
}
```

When I dump `$this->market()`, it returns `BelongsTo object` and `$this->market`, it returns  `null`.

Also, `$this->market()->toSql()` returns

```
select * from `markets` where `markets`.`id` is null
```

Strange thing is, it works actually fine just yesterday and I didn't change its code....;; I believe unknown side effect can cause this but I never experience those kine of issue. Any insight help...

Comment: Can you do `dd($this->id)`, maybe because the id is null

Comment: the foreign key at `Sequence` model is `market_id` ?

Comment: if `$sequence->market_id` is `null`, then `$sequence->market` will be `null` as well. Is that the case?

Comment: `Sequence` model has proper foreign key and the foreign key is `market_id` as well.

Comment: @aceraven777 Yes! Its not only id, every attribute not accessible;;; all returns null on magic method or `getAttribute()` method;

Comment: I meant `dd($this->market_id)`, well @IGP is right if `market_id` is `null`, then the sql will be `null` as well, can you show us how are you calling this from your controller? can you provide us the complete code?

Comment: ...I just got answered. Coworker pooling me off.. end of a class there is a empty getAttribute method..

Thanks for all help;;.. im closing this question...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.. I just found that there is an empty method `getAttribute($key)`.. and coworker said he made some joke.